# How can I reopen a file inside a function that was read in another function?

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am using csv.DictReader, DictWriter.

I have a function that reads the file and, thus it seems, closes it. In another function I need to add more to it but I keep getting:
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Code looks like: At module level:

```
FILE = 'finished_emails.csv'

with open(FILE, 'r') as DONE:
    READER = DictReader(DONE)
    FINISHED = [e['email'] for e in READER]
```

The next at module level:

```
with open(FILE, 'a+') as DONE:
    FIELDS = ['email']
    WRITER = DictWriter(DONE, FIELDS)
```

Then inside a function:

```
    WRITER.writerow({'email': email})
```

I'm just trying to keep track of a bunch of emails that have been sent so that if the script crashes I can start where I left off.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `with` statement closes the file as soon as you unindent your code. You should pass the opened file object to the function that's writing the data, and call the function inside the `with` statement:

```
def example_func(writer, data):
    writer.writerow({'email': data[0]})

with open(FILE, 'a+') as DONE:
    FIELDS = ['email']
    WRITER = DictWriter(DONE, FIELDS)
    example_func(WRITER, FIELDS)
```